# Watch on factory object not working in a custom directive's controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am setting up a basic e-commerce interface using Angular.js.

Basically I want the added to cart div in the main navigation bar to pop up when the add to cart button is clicked. That is what is done using the click1 variable in mainNavbar directive controller.

I have a controller for the top navigation bar which is used as a custom directive,

```
app.directive('mainNavbar',function(){
return {
restrict:'E',
templateUrl:'partials/nav.html',
controller:'navController',
link:function(scope,element)
{
   scope.$watch('click1',function(value){
   if(value==1)
   {
      $('#cart').css('display','block');
   }
   else 
   {
      $('#cart').css('display','none');
   }
   });
 }
};
});

app.controller("navController",function($scope,thefactory,$q,$routeParams)
{
    $scope.count=0;
    $scope.click1=0;
    $scope.cart_amt=0;
    $scope.cartdata=[];
    $scope.showcrt=function()
    {
        $scope.cart_amt=thefactory.cart_amt;
        var i=0;
        while(i<thefactory.prods.length)
        {
            $scope.cartdata[i]=thefactory.prods[i];
            i++;  
         }
         thefactory.setcartval(1);
         $scope.click1=1;
     };
    $scope.hidecart=function()
    {
        $scope.click1=0;
        thefactory.setcartval(0);
    };
    $scope.$watch('thefactory', function (newVal,oldVal,scope)
    {
       if (typeof newVal == 'undefined') {

       }
       else
       {
          if(newVal.getcartval()==1)
          {
              scope.showcrt();
          }
          if(newVal.numcartelem>oldVal.numcartelem)
          {
              scope.count=newVal;
          }
      }
   });
  });
```

a factory

```
app.factory('thefactory',function($http,$q)
{
   var factory={};
   factory.products=[];
   factory.cart_amt=0;
   factory.prods=[];
   factory.numcartelem=0;
   var showcart=0;
   factory.getcartval=function()
   {
      return showcart;
   };
   factory.setcartval=function(a)
   {
      showcart=a;
   };
   factory.addprod2cart=function(a,b,c,d)
   {
      factory.cart_amt+=c;
      factory.numcartelem++;
      factory.prods.push({'heading':a,'seller':b,'price':c,'img':d});
   };
   return factory;
});
```

and another controller for adding a product to cart.

```
app.controller("productController", function($scope,thefactory,$q,$routeParams)
{
    $scope.data=[];
    $scope.product_id = $routeParams.productId;
    $scope.data=thefactory.products[$scope.product_id-1];
    $scope.addcart=function(a,b,c,d)
    {
       console.log("Add to cart called!");
       thefactory.addprod2cart(a,b,c,d);
    };
});
```

Now, the problem is, the watch on factory object doesn't get called in navController even though the add to cart function is called in productController which must be calling the factory addprod2cart function and changing the factory object.
I am sure that the factory object is modified because if I click on the cart button in my navigation bar, I see the updated object. But, the watch on that object doesn't work. Please suggest a solution for the same. Thanks!

Comment: Please use proper code indent formatting so it is readable

Comment: Proper code indenting done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the watch expression.

Try adding `thefactory` to scope

```
$scope.thefactory = thefactory;
$scope.$watch('thefactory', function (newVal,oldVal,scope) {}, true);
```

or

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return thefactory;
}, function (newVal,oldVal,scope) { }, true);
```

Comment: The same problem persists.

Comment: @sam1993 pass the 3rd param as true as you are watching for changes inside an object